# How to use loop to do rolling calculation in J

Tags: j

I want to use a function to calculate value in a rolling window of 30 for a list numbers. To be specific, a list of 100 numbers, I need to use the number 0 to 29 to calculate the first ,then the number 1 to 30 and so on. Last should be 71 to 100. Finally I need to get a list of result.(70 numbers) If the function are below,

```
cumulativeR=: 4 : 0
a=.(x+30)}y
b=.x{y
(a-b)%b
)
```

I tried to use loop function like while or for, but I just cannot write it like

```
x=.1 2 3 4 5 6 ………… 70
f=:3:0
'x y z'=. y
r=.0
for_i. x
do. i{r =. z cumulativeR y
end.
)
```

I cannot get a list of result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic solution would be to use the [\ dyadic adverb](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/bslash#dyadic).

```
   5 ]\ i.10
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have another question. How should I use function to each row at one time? For example, if I want to use \:@\: to each row, how should I do?

Comment: The example uses `]` as the function, but more generally you would define a function `f =. \:@\:` and then apply it as in this answer: `5 f\ data` where `data` is your 100 item list.